# StackOverflowError - Loop infinito ao fazer deploy de ear com ejb e demoiselle

Tags: java, ejb, demoiselle, java-ee-6

Ao fazer o *deploy* de um EAR com um EJB que depende do *demoiselle-core*, uma exceção do **StackOverflowError** é lançada.

Ocorre que ao tentar criar um *ResourceBundle* (ResourceBundleProducer.createNamed(ResourceBundleProducer.java:77)) a classe Beans (linha 159) lança uma *NoSuchElementException* que é tratada no bloco:

```java
} catch (NoSuchElementException cause) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(beanClass.getCanonicalName());

    if (qualifiers != null) {
        for (Annotation qualifier : qualifiers) {
            buffer.append(", ");
            buffer.append(qualifier.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        }
    }

    String message = getBundle().getString("bean-not-found", buffer.toString());
    throw new DemoiselleException(message, cause);
}
```

Ou seja, o bloco *catch* depende do *ResourceBundle* e entra no *loop* infinito.

Por algum motivo a dependência Locale do *ResourceBundle* não é satisfeita e o método `BeanManager.getBeans()` retorna um *EmptyImmutableSet* causando a *NoSuchElementException*.

A aplicação de exemplo está em: https://bitbucket.org/juliannoms/demoiselle-ear-teste .

Obs.: Antes da versão 2.4.0-BETA2 o erro ocorria somente na classe que injetava o *ResourceBundle* e não no *deploy* da aplicação.

**Edição**:

Após estudar o código do *demoiselle* ([github.com/demoiselle](https://github.com/demoiselle)), percebi que se o meu projeto dependesse de um dos pacotes - `demoiselle-se` ou `demoiselle-servlet` - o objeto da classe *java.util.Locale* poderia ser injetado resolvendo assim a exception lançada *NoSuchElementException*.

O resultado é que todo projeto que dependa do *demoiselle-core* também deve depender de uma destas duas dependências para funcionar corretamente.